# Changing Font colour (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, fonts, colors

i'm trying to change the font colour of the text on a desktop ticker.

This is the code i currently have:

```
Private Sub loadthenews()
str = ""
myArray.Clear()
fo = New Font("CALIBRI", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)
Dim readXML As New XmlTextReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\news.xml")
```

How can i change the colour to something non standard i.e. a HEX or RGB colour.

Thank you

Edit....

I'm looking here:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or _
ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or _
ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)
e.Graphics.DrawString(str, fo, Brushes.Black, widthX, heightY + 5)
```

However i need to change the brushes colour from Black to a Hex or RGB color.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Font` objects don't have a colour. The colour the text appears in is specified elsewhere, e.g. the `ForeColor` of a control or via a `Brush` when calling `Graphics.DrawString`.  You need to find where that colour is set in your specific case and set it there.

Comment: See which control is used to output the XML content. That control has a `ForeColor` property. If the text is instead drawn on a control surface (this is something that is relatively common when building a marquee-like control or using a standard control class (`TextBox`, `Label`) as a marquee), the `Paint()` event of that control should have created a `Brush` object with a specific Color.

Comment: Updated question, thank you both for the help so far!

Comment: Move that `SetStyle()` call out of the `Paint()` event ASAP. That one goes in the Form's (or any other class) **Constructor** (`Sub New()`).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this is now working

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new brush:

```
Dim brush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100,100,100))
```

Then you can use it instead of the black brush:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(str, fo, brush, widthX, heightY + 5)
```